# Execute service builder generated sql file on postgresql

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, postgresql, liferay

I would like to execute sql files generated by the service builder, but the problem is that the sql files contains types like: LONG,VARCHAR... etc

Some of these types don't exist on Postgresql (for example LONG is Bigint).

I don't know if there is a simple way to convert sql file's structures to be able to run them on Postgresql?

Comment: "The service builder". What service builder?

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/fr/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/service-build-2

Comment: Those sql files are not "final" sql queries to execute. They're designed for ServiceBuilder and not for human usage. ServiceBuilder is modifying them based on the detected database server, before running them in liferay. So you will need to dive deep into the ServiceBuilder source code to see what's going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniele is right, using `build-db` task is obviously correct and is the right way to do it.

But... I remember a similar situation some time ago, I had only liferay-pseudo-sql file and need to create proper DDL. I managed to do this in the following way:

You need to have Liferay running on your desktop (or in the machine where is the source sql file), as this operation requires portal spring context fully wired.

- Go to Configuration -> Server Administration -> Script
- Change language to groovy

Run the following script:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.db.DB
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.db.DBFactoryUtil

DB db = DBFactoryUtil.getDB(DB.TYPE_POSTGRESQL)

db.buildSQLFile("/path/to/folder/with/your/sql", "filename")
```

Where first parameter is obviously the path and the second is filename **without `.sql` extension**. The file on disk should have proper extension: must be called `filename.sql`.

This will produce `tables` folder next to your `filename.sql` which will contain single `tables-postgresql.sql` with your Postgres DDL.

As far as I remember, Service Builder uses the same method to generate database-specific code.

Answer (score 3):

execute `ant build-db` on the plugin and you will find sql folder with vary vendor specific scripts.

Comment: Excuse me sir, but I think that you went so far
the situation is very simple, I have a file.sql and I would like to run it on an postgresql database, this sqlfile is generated by liferay the problem is that I couldn't run this script (or sql file) because it doesn't respect postgresql syntaxe... for exemple:

postgresql can accept: 
create table entity(
id Bigint not null primary key,
);

and no:
create table entity(
id LONGnot null primary key,
);

I think that liferay can manage this story and adapt the scripts generated by service builder with the appropriate SGBD!

Comment: did you execute `ant build-db`? This will create a folder in `docroot/WEB-INF/sql/create` (and others, parallel), just like Daniele described. A sample filename in there is `create-postgresql.sql`